# How to show correctly tabulation in xsl-fo?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an XML document and I am creating an XSL-FO file to convert it to pdf with apache-fop.

In the xml, there are sections <code> to show... code.

In the xsl-fo, I added the white-space="pre" sentence to preserve the code format, but tabulations are shown like single space:

XML section:

```
<code><![CDATA[
function callback( widget )
{
    var ui = widget; // It should be a tab
}
]]></code>
```

XSL-FO section:

```
<xsl:template match="code">
    <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="monospace" white-space="pre" color="#008000" background-color="#f8f8f8">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Resulting PDF:

```
function callback( widget )
{
 var ui = widget;  // It should be a tab
}
```

So my question is: **How to preserve or set the size of the tabulation?**

---

Edited: I am using apache-fop 1.1

A full example:

proyecto.xml (do not forget to replace the 4 spaces by a tab before "var ui...")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="proyecto.xsl"?>
<document>
<code><![CDATA[
function callback( widget )
{
    var ui = widget; // It should be a tab
}
]]></code>
</document>
```

proyecto.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:template match ="document">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="OnePage" margin="1in" 
                    page-height="29.7cm" 
                    page-width="21cm"
                    margin-top="2.5cm"
                    margin-bottom="2.5cm"
                    margin-left="3.5cm"
                    margin-right="2.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin="0cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Page">
                    <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="OnePage"/>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="monospace" white-space="pre">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <!--<xsl:value-of select="replace( . , 'a', 'b')"/>-->
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PDF result (screen):

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more context. That is, an actual XML input sample and the XSLT stylesheet that transforms it into XSL-FO. Otherwise, we cannot reproduce your issue. By the way, say what XSLT processor and versions you are working with (XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, version of FOP).

Comment: This might help: http://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200707/msg00213.html.

Comment: @Mathias Müller: I just added an xsl-fo section, but the whole xml take about 100pages and the xsl-fo some pages also. The apache-fop version is the last one 1.1, which is compatible with most of XSL-FO 1.1

Comment: @AdrianMaire I was asking you to provide _any_ stylesheet and input XML that expose your problem. It can be simple, but make sure what troubles you is still there. Only then can we _reproduce_ your problem, otherwise all bets are off. @mzjn `white-space="pre"` should already set those attributes, http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#white-space.

Comment: @mzjn: Your solution sound good, but at the moment I am unable to make replace() to work. I still looking what is the issue: apache-fop say something about "wrong type"

Answer (score 1):

Replace the tabs by four spaces, as suggested by @mzjn already in the comments.

**XML Input**

```
<code><![CDATA[
function callback( widget )
{
&#09;var ui = widget; // It should be a tab
}
]]></code>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-portrait"
              page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="2cm">
          <fo:region-body/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-portrait">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-family="monospace" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve" wrap-option="no-wrap" color="#008000" background-color="#f8f8f8">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(code,'&#09;','    ')"/>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, after replacing the tab characters with whitespaces, the output is rendered correctly by FOP.

> [image]

There is no obvious flaw with outputting tabs, but bear in mind that Apache FOP is only *partially* compliant in regard to the `whitespace-treatment` property: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html , even if it says that only `fo:inline` elements are affected of this.

Comment: The problem is maybe of apache-fop, but as you see in the image I just added, the tab look like one space.

Comment: @AdrianMaire What does FOP say about a "wrong type"?

Comment: Only related with the solution from Mzjn, and probably because of a bad use, when i try to use the "replace" functor, apache-fop throw:
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(replace, [step("child", 15), literal-expr(        ), literal-expr(    )])'.'

Comment: You are probably using XSLT 1.0 which does not have the `replace` function. Can you upgrade the XSLT version?

Comment: I am using apache-fop 1.1, which is supposed to be compliant with XSLT-FO 1.1 / XSLT 1.1. I may change to another renderer of course if there is no other solution.

Comment: How about transforming the XML input with an XSLT 2.0 processor (e.g. Saxon 9.5) to XSL-FO first, and as a second step let FOP render the output?

Comment: It is easier to make a script that replace tabs by spaces before to call fop. So yes, there are possibilities outside of XSLT. Thanks you