# XSL-FO tabs characters still collapsing

Tags: xml, whitespace, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm trying to put some tabulations between some elements in this XSL-FO stylesheet. The problem is that even if I set white-space-collapse to false and white-space-treatment to preserve they still collapse into a single space.

I'm using XSL-FO stylesheets to turn some XML info into a formatted PDF. I'm using FOP 1.1 for Java.

Here is the code:

```
<fo:block white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="preserve" 
            white-space="pre" wrap-option="no-wrap" linefeed-treatment="preserve">
    <xsl:value-of select="VARIOS/LOC1"/> <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="VARIOS/LOC2"/> <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="VARIOS/LOC3"/> <xsl:text>&#x09;</xsl:text> 
    <xsl:value-of select="VARIOS/LOC4"/>     
</fo:block>
```

Thanks in advice!
Have a nice code!

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361191/how-to-show-correctly-tabulation-in-xsl-fo

I don't use FOP, but it sounds like you're best off converting the tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Tab characters are not part of XSL FO. Depending on what you desire there are different methods to obtain the view you want. Based on your snippet I would say to use a table if multirow alignment or specific columns are desired